# Using IN operator in combination with other predicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a left join query. I have two predicates in the where clause. First I'm using the IN operator with a select statement. In the second predicate I'm checking if `IsActive` column is true. However, I'm not allowed to use & operator as I have done below - I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near &

Code:

```
select Table1.Id 
from Table1
left Join Table2 on Table1.Id = Table2.Table1Id
where Table1.IntColumn in (select Table3.IntColumn 
                           from Table3
                           where Table1.Id = Table3.Id) 
    & Table1.IsActive = 1    -- this is not allowed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use an `AND` operator.

Comment: `&` is a [Bitwise AND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-and-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15); it doesn't make sense where you have it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `and`?

```
select Table1.Id 
from Table1 Left Join
     Table2
     On Table1.Id= Table2.Table1Id
where Table1.IntColumn in (Select Table3.IntColumn
                           from Table3
                           where Table1.Id = Table3.Id
                          ) and
      Table1.IsActive = 1)
```

Comment: thanks , thought I was still programming in c#   :).